# Trying to get property of non-object | Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Error : Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xamppp\htdocs\filmeseriale\resources\views\admin\seriall\show.blade.php)

Controller

> ```
> public function store(Request $request)
> {
>     $serial = new Serial();
>     $serial->nume_serial = $request['nume_serial'];
>     $serial->slug = $request['slug'];
>     $serial->data_lansare = $request['data_lansare'];
>     $serial->genuri = $request['genuri'];
>     $serial->stare = $request['stare'];
>     $serial->durata = $request['durata'];
>     $serial->trailer = $request['trailer'];
>     $serial->regizor = $request['regizor'];
>     $serial->distributie = $request['distributie'];
>     $serial->limba_vorbita = $request['limba_vorbita'];
>     $serial->tara = $request['tara'];
>     $serial->nota_imdb = $request['nota_imdb'];
>     $serial->imagine = $request['imagine'];
>     $serial->informatii = $request['informatii'];
>     $serial->save();
>     return redirect()->route('admin.seriall.show',[$serial->slug]);
> }
>
>
>
> public function show($slug)
> {
>     $serial = Serial::find($slug);
>
>     return view('admin.seriall.show')->with('serial',$serial);
> }
> ```

View

```
@section('content')
    <h1>{{ ($serial->nume_serial) }}</h1>
    @endsection
```

Comment: I believe find() expects an integer, not a string. Try replacing Serial::find($slug) with Serial::where('slug', $slug)->first()

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert with laravel...  But I think that you are passing an array to the view...  Does the laravels orm have a function like findone or finbyid??

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:
 1. model is not saved, so you should check this expression `$serial->save();`
 2. May be slug is not your primary key? `find()` is used to retrieve a model by its primary key

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent\Model::find() expects an integer, ie. the primary key. Try replacing

```
$serial = Serial::find($slug);
```

with:

```
$serial = Serial::where('slug', $slug)->first()
```